# Non-responsive website in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I need to create a non responsive website in WordPress (don’t ask, no my choice). So basically, I need a site that looks exactly the same on all devices, from desktop to mobile, just scaled down (not cuted off on mobile versions. I need to see the whole site on mobile and tablets, only scaled, so if someone wants to read something he will zoom in I guess). I plan to use some theme as a base, I will not code site from scratch. Perfect example is viventura.de. Any suggestion will help. 
Thanks

Comment: So what advice you are seeking?

Comment: How to achive this. But, I managed to solve problem (at least big part). Insted of: `content="width=device-width` I added: `content="width=1024"`

Answer (score 0):

Usually, themes use media-queries and viewport to make the responsive work.

Just remove the viewport line in the html code and the user will need to zoom to read something because media queries will no longer work.

The viewport line is in the head section in header.php file, and it looks like this :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, initial-scale=1" />
```

You can also delete all the media queries in the .css file, media queries look like this :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    // some CSS code
}
```

But I advice you to use the first solution in case you want to reactivate the responsive later. So just comment the meta viewport line.

Comment: I tried to comment meta viewpoint on default Twenty Sixteen theme and for some reason nothing changed. Then I removed a piece  of code above from header.php and added:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">` 

instead, and it worked. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.